# Android Rx - combine two observables to a third one

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have two observables like:

```
Observable<Contact> contacts = getAllContacts();
Observable<Message> messages = getAllMessages();
```

getting all contacts and messages from a local database.

The Contact class is:

```
class Contact {
  String name;
  String phoneNumber;
}
```

The Message class is:

```
class Message {
  String content;
  String fromNumber;
}
```

I want to recreate a classic "thread" view, like SMS/Whatsapp apps.
So I wanna "combine" contacts and messages, obtaining an Observable, each MessageThread containing the Contact and the list of Message(s), so the MessageThread class is like:

```
class MessageThread {
  Contact contact;
  List<Message> messages;
}
```

I did something like:

```
        Observable<MessageThread> response = messages.zipWith(contacts, (message, contact) -> {
        MessageThread thread = new MessageThread();
        thread.setContact(contact);
        thread.addMessage(message);
        return thread;
    });
```

but there's no "check" about phone numbers, the logic is completely missing.

Any suggestion how to approach this problem using Observables?

Comment: How would you do it without using Rx?

Comment: Like an HashMap<Contact,List<Message>>, loop on contacts and add them to the hashmap. 
Then for each message, add to the list of the correct contact, then remove all keys without values.
Finally, loop on hashmap and create the list of MessageThread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
contacts
.toMap(contact->contact.phoneNumber, contact->contact)
.flatMap(phones -> messages.toMultiMap(
    message -> phones.get(message.fromNumber))
```

This should give you a `Map<Contact, Collection<Message>>`.

Edit: for MessageThreads, this should do the trick:

```
contacts
.toMap(contact->contact.phoneNumber, contact->contact)
.flatMap(phones -> messages.groupBy(message -> phones.get(message.fromNumber))
.flatMap(group -> group.toList().map(list -> new MessageThread(group.getKey(), list)));
```

Assuming that the appropriate MessageThread constructor exists, of course.